# Use gRPC to communicate between containers

Tags: docker, go, grpc

I'm implementing two services (server and client) running on two different containers and trying to use gRPC to communicate between them.

If I deploy the server as a container and run the client **not** on a container, everything works just fine. But if I deploy the client on a different container I get `Error #01: could not retrieve restaurant's list: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = grpc: the connection is unavailable` error.

What steps am I missing to communicate two different containers using gRPC?

PS: I would like to try without Kubernetes for now.

**SERVER**

```
func Serve() {

    log.Println("serving...")

    port := ":50051"

    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", port)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen on port %s: %v", port, err)
    }

    s := grpc.NewServer()
    server := server{}
    RegisterNeo4BaconServer(s, server)

    if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("could not serve: ", err)
    }
}
```

**Makefile**

```
image: ## build docker image and push image to registry
    @docker build -t neo4bacon -f resources/prod/Dockerfile .

run: ## deploy application container
    @docker run --rm -d --name neo4bacon neo4bacon
```

**CLIENT**

```
func Get() (*api.RestaurantList, error) {
    // Neo4bacon backend
    backendPort := ":50051"

    conn, err := grpc.Dial(backendPort, grpc.WithInsecure())
    if err != nil {
        &api.RestaurantList{}, fmt.Errorf("could not connect to backend %s: %s", backendPort, err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    client := api.NewNeo4BaconClient(conn)

    restaurantList, err := client.List(context.Background(), &api.Empty{})
    if err != nil {
        return &api.RestaurantList{}, fmt.Errorf("could not retrieve restaurant's list: %s", err)
    }
    return restaurantList, nil
}
```

**Makefile**

```
image: ## build docker image and push image to registry     
@docker build -t alesr/bacon-api -f resources/prod/Dockerfile .     

run: ## deploy docker container     
@docker run --rm -d -p 8080:8080 --name bacon-api bacon-api
```

Comment: Where in the client code do you specify the server host to connect to? I don't see that...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to include the hostname in the dial function, otherwise it's looking at localhost which is unique to each container (docker creates a separate networking namespace for containers by default). Change the following:

```
backendPort := "neo4bacon:50051"
```

Edit: you also need to setup a network and connect the containers to that network because the default bridge does not include DNS discovery:

```
docker network create baconnet
docker run --rm -d --net baconnet --name neo4bacon neo4bacon
docker run --rm -d --net baconnet -p 8080:8080 --name bacon-api bacon-api
```

Answer (score 0):

If your gRPC client and server are hosted on docker, to establish the connection between to container you should follow the below steps.

1. First, you should create a docker network.

   `docker network create web_server --driver bridge`
2. Then register your containers with the created network. You should mention the service name and the network in the docker run command.

   `docker run -dit -p 3000:3000 --name question-service --network web_server ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/question-service:latest`
3. Now your URL should format as below,

> {{service-name}}:port

as an example

```
question-service:3000
```

for more details, you can refer to this [blog](https://blog.sathyamolagoda.me/docker-network-for-communication-between-grpc-client-and-server)